# GDI+ DrawImage has different output results when using a printer to print images on a low DPI system and a high DPI system

Tags: c++, gdi+, printers

when I print an image using GDI+ DrawImage method on a high DPI system, the result differs from what printer is used. Next is my test code:

```cpp
using namespace Gdiplus;

void printImage(std::wstring printerDriverName, std::wstring printerName, std::wstring printerPortName, PDEVMODEW pDevMode)
{
    GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR m_gdiplusToken;
    GdiplusStartup(&m_gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);

    HDC hDC = ::CreateDCW(printerDriverName.c_str(),printerName.c_str(), printerPortName.c_str(), pDevMode);

    DOCINFOW sDocInfo;
    memset(&sDocInfo, 0, sizeof(DOCINFOW));
    sDocInfo.cbSize = sizeof(sDocInfo);
    sDocInfo.lpszDocName = "test";
    ::StartDocW(hdc, &sDocInfo);

    // Printed area
    int printLeft = ::GetDeviceCaps(hDC, PHYSICALOFFSETX);
    int printLop = ::GetDeviceCaps(hDC, PHYSICALOFFSETY);
    int printWidth = ::GetDeviceCaps(hDC, HORZRES);
    int printHeight = ::GetDeviceCaps(hDC, VERTRES);

    // Load PNG pictures
    std::unique_ptr<Bitmap> pBitmap = std::make_unique<Bitmap>("C:/Desktop/test.png");
    if (Ok == pBitmap->GetLastStatus())
    {
        // Start printing
        ::StartPage(hdc);

        Graphics printGraphics(hDC);
        printGraphics.SetPageUnit(UnitPixel);
        printGraphics.DrawImage(pBitmap.get(), printLeft , printLop , printWidth , printHeight );
        ::EndPage(hdc);
    }

    ::EndDoc(hdc);
    ::DeleteDC(hDC);

    GdiplusShutdown(m_gdiplusToken);
}
```

I'll use numbers to represent image pixels, e.g.:

1111111111222222
1111111111222222
1111111111222222
1111111111222222
1111111111222222
2222222222222222
2222222222222222

When I run this code against the attached image on a 96 DPI desktop system, everything is fine when printing on Microsoft PrintToPDF as well as any other installed printer.Both "1" and "2" parts are printed normally:

1111111111222222
1111111111222222
1111111111222222
1111111111222222
1111111111222222
2222222222222222
2222222222222222

Next I run the same code on a SurfacePro 7 with 192 DPI.  Now the result differs from used printer:  HP Universal PS produce the expected output:

1111111111222222
1111111111222222
1111111111222222
1111111111222222
1111111111222222
2222222222222222
2222222222222222

But Microsoft Print to PDF, HP Laserjet 400 MFP M425dw (607BA1) printer creates a wrong output: rectangle size is fine but content not.Only the "1" part is on the paper, the "2" part is missing.

1111111111
1111111111
1111111111
1111111111
1111111111

Why produces the output on different printers different outputs? what causes this problem?

Thanks.

Is it because the DPI of the printer is different from the DPI of the picture?Or because the DPI of the printer is different from that of the screen

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/gdiplusgraphics/nf-gdiplusgraphics-graphics-drawimage(image_constrectf__constrectf__unit_constimageattributes)